# Output image of CNN autoencoder is white

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science, autoencoder

I'm having trouble training an autoencoding CNN. My objective is to cluster document images (receipts, letters, etc.) in an unsupervised fashion (btw do you have other algorithms besides autoencoders for this?).

So I tried to do an autoencoder, and I'm always getting weird decoded outputs, I don't know what's the problem. I started with a very simple model without a lot of compression :

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_62 (Conv2D)           (None, 100, 76, 16)       448       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_62 (Activation)   (None, 100, 76, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_63 (Conv2D)           (None, 50, 38, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_63 (Activation)   (None, 50, 38, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_64 (Conv2D)           (None, 50, 38, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_64 (Activation)   (None, 50, 38, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_26 (UpSampling (None, 100, 76, 32)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_65 (Conv2D)           (None, 100, 76, 16)       4624      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_65 (Activation)   (None, 100, 76, 16)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_27 (UpSampling (None, 200, 152, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_66 (Conv2D)           (None, 200, 152, 3)       435       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_66 (Activation)   (None, 200, 152, 3)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 19,395
Trainable params: 19,395
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I trained with a small number of inputs (~200) so that the training is fast and I can debug faster.

It seems the model is converging after 20 epochs and a batch size of 32 :

```
Epoch 1/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.4359
Epoch 2/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.4290
Epoch 3/20
4/4 [==============================] - 4s 904ms/step - loss: 0.4192
Epoch 4/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.4045
Epoch 5/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 783ms/step - loss: 0.3886
Epoch 6/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 797ms/step - loss: 0.3706
Epoch 7/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.3393
Epoch 8/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 777ms/step - loss: 0.3165
Epoch 9/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 850ms/step - loss: 0.2786
Epoch 10/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 780ms/step - loss: 0.2436
Epoch 11/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 817ms/step - loss: 0.2036
Epoch 12/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 771ms/step - loss: 0.1745
Epoch 13/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.1347
Epoch 14/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 820ms/step - loss: 0.1150
Epoch 15/20
4/4 [==============================] - 5s 1s/step - loss: 0.1017
Epoch 16/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 792ms/step - loss: 0.0886
Epoch 17/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 789ms/step - loss: 0.0868
Epoch 18/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 842ms/step - loss: 0.0844
Epoch 19/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 762ms/step - loss: 0.0797
Epoch 20/20
4/4 [==============================] - 3s 779ms/step - loss: 0.0768
```

But the output images look all something like this :

[output of autoencoder (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1WQE.png)

For loss I used the mean absolute error and an SGD optimizer (the others don't converge very well).

I tried to push the number of epochs but the loss stagnates at around 0.07 and doesn't go down.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas to improve it? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's the code

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, zca_whitening=False, rotation_range=0.2, width_shift_range=0.005, height_shift_range=0.005, zoom_range=0.005)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory('fp_img',class_mode='input',target_size=image_dims, batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Reshape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

input_shape = image_rgb_dims

# Define the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=2, padding='same', input_shape=image_rgb_dims))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(32,(3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16,(3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(3,(3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.summary()

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adagrad', loss='mean_absolute_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch= n_images // batch_size,
        epochs=20)
```

Comment: there's probably a bud in your code somewhere. Can you share your code?

Comment: I just edited and added the code at the end

Comment: The images are mainly white (because there's text on it), so perhaps that's why it's overfitting to it and the outputs are all white?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

- You're trying to create an autoencoder to cluster images, but your embedding is not one-dimensional. How are you going to cluster your images? You'll need Dense layers or more Conv layer to go to a 1 dimensional vector to be able to cluster on euclidean distance.
- What happens when you try training on just 1 non-data-augmented image? Does your network overfit to generate that single image, or do you still get white images? If it's the former, the network is indeed overfitting to just generate white pixels. A solution is to penalize 'not generating black pixels' in the loss function. If it's the latter you still have a bug somewhere, maybe you're not scaling the image properly.
- 200 images is are not that many images, I wouldn't try to validate the performance of your model on such a small dataset for an autoencoder.
- Do all your images have text? You could try preprocessing your images by using OCR and cluster based on what words appear, not on the image. Features could even be just the number of words, or the number of digits...
- If you stick to the CNN, I would try to resize your images to be a lot smaller if it's for clustering, right now there pretty big for a network you want to train from scratch.

Comment: I just tried my code (and the complete model with the dense) with a lena image, and after 200 iterations on it, the output was very good which means my data is the problem (too much white).

Comment: I would try training with a lot more images first! You can also try inverting black and white, if your images come up black, you're very sure that it's overfitting. I hope my tips can get you started!

Answer (score 0):

Are the images you're trying to display all matrices with uint8 values within the 0-255 range?

I've seen white screens before when trying to display images, and it was because they where in the right value range, but they were still float32.